# PHP Array Order by Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is my array:

```
    Array ( [nse_h_a] => 2351 [nse_h_b] => 6119 [nse_h_c] => 2496 [nse_h_d] => 402 [nse_h_e] => 180 )
```

And I want to sort the array by key values not

sort, ksort and krsort dont work.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you think that ksort/krsort would work? http://php.net/ksort `Sort an array by key`

Comment: `asort()` if you want to maintain the keys, otherwise `sort()` should work fine

Comment: Can you explain why `sort` did not work? It certainly should have worked.

Comment: I solve it! 

function aksort(&$array,$valrev=false,$keyrev=false) {
  if ($valrev) { arsort($array); } else { asort($array); }
    $vals = array_count_values($array);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($vals AS $val=>$num) {
        $first = array_splice($array,0,$i);
        $tmp = array_splice($array,0,$num);
        if ($keyrev) { krsort($tmp); } else { ksort($tmp); }
        $array = array_merge($first,$tmp,$array);
        unset($tmp);
        $i = $num;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Use [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

```
$isShorted = asort($myArray);
```

Comment: True, although in your example, it will simply set your `$array` variable to bool(true)

Comment: @Battle_707 Oups, you're right, fixed...